# Spring XD as a Rest Endpoint

Tags: spring-xd

Can we integrate Spring XD and Spring MVC, so that we can ingest/process data sent to the REST end point?

We have huge amounts of data collected in a Spring MVC app and are wondering if we could use Spring XD for this.

Comment: Are you looking for something more than the http source?

Comment: yeah ... Actually I was thinking if I could define traditional Rest endpoint on XD for ingestion..

Answer (score 0):

The `http` source is a stripped-down http server (based on netty); it is not a full Spring MVC server. For that, you would need a custom source with an embedded tomcat/jetty.

See Artem's comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244348/creating-a-custom-websocket-sink-for-spring-xd/29250132#29250132) for a suggestion about how to embed tomcat in a module.